# Multiple responses in SPSS

Tags: count, spss

I have multiple response questions which have 5 categories (values). I want to get respondents who answered only one category.
For example,
Respondents who answered category not 2,3,4,5.
[image]
[image]
I want only A mentions like, who are all checked A category alone. I need count of this.
Help, Please.

Comment: Please describe the structure of your data so we can help find a solution for your problem

Comment: @eli-k you can find the further details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following solution is assuming the data has 5 dichotomous variables - one for each of the multiple response categories.

```
* creating some sample data to demonstrate on.
data list list/cat1 to cat5.
begin data
    1 0 0 0 1
    0 1 1 0 0
    1 0 0 0 0
    0 1 0 0 0
    0 0 1 0 0
    0 0 0 0 1
    1 0 0 0 0
    1 1 1 0 0
end data.

* now checking in which cases only category 1 was chosen.
compute NumCats=sum(cat1 to cat5).
if cat1=1 and NumCats=1 onlyCat1=1.
execute.

* if instead you wish to do the same check for each of the 5 categories,  
  use `do repeat` this way.

do repeat cat=cat1 to cat5/only=only1 to only5.
    compute only=(cat=1 and NumCats=1).
end repeat.
execute.
```

Comment: @prabhu. this answer is good if you have a separate variable for each category, with 0 or 1 marked if the category was chosen. If this is not how the data's built, please add a full explanation and i'll add a fitting solution

Comment: Thank you, I was looking for this solution.

Answer (score 0):

But ditch the EXECUTE commands.  They just cause a useless data pass in this case except for immediately updating the Data Editor (instead of updating on the next data pass).

Comment: But if the statement does not end with execute, creates an error.

Comment: That should not cause an error.  What was the error message, and where did it occur?